# Fastlane & React-Native: Google Api Error: Invalid request - Access Not Configured

Tags: android, react-native, fastlane

What causes the below error when using Fastlane and React-Native after running this :

`fastlane beta`

```
[22:36:39]: Google Api Error: Invalid request - Access Not Configured. Google Play Developer API has not been used in project xxxxx before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/androidpublisher.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxx then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

+------+----------------------+-------------+
|             fastlane summary              |
+------+----------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action               | Time (in s) |
+------+----------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform     | 0           |
| 2    | bundleRelease        | 18          |
|    | upload_to_play_store | 1           |
+------+----------------------+-------------+

[22:36:39]: fastlane finished with errors

[!] Google Api Error: Invalid request - Access Not Configured. Google Play Developer API has not been used in project xxxxx before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/androidpublisher.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxx then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

This is how my Fastfile:

```
platform :android do
  desc "Runs all the tests"
  lane :test do
    gradle(task: "test")
  end

  lane :beta do
  # Adjust the `build_type` and `flavor` params as needed to build the right APK for your setup
  gradle(
    task: 'bundle',
    build_type: 'Release'
  )
  upload_to_play_store(track: 'beta',
  skip_upload_apk: true,
     aab: 'app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab'
  )
  end

  desc "Deploy a new version to the Google Play"
  lane :deploy do
    gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease")
    upload_to_play_store
  end
end
```

Have enabled `Google Play Developer API` too for the project.

Anyone here who can quickly help me solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Something that you can do but may not be your preferred solution is including the parameter "json_key_data" in your upload_to_play_store command.

More info here: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_play_store/